# dynamic edittext inside listview with watcher

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-listview

Here am trying to make a simple android app that simulate sales man work just as this [picture](http://www.4shared.com/photo/XRdPp0Im/Untitled.html?) ,

I receive the items ,price,and the quantity of the item from a web service in string list i found this [Tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/12/android-attach-textwatcher-to-multiple-edittext.html)  that can solve my problem but i couldn't customize it to pass the string list i retrieve from my web service.

Here is my webservice code :

```
public List<String> getProduct() {

try {   
     // Accessing driver from jar files  
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     // here we create a variable for the connection called con 
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root", "root");
     // here we create our query       
     PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("select quantity,price,item FROM distribute");
     //PreparedStatement statement2= con.prepareStatement("select Date FROM storage_other");
     // Here we are going to create a variable to Execute the query     
     ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery();   
     //int i=1;
     while (rs.next()) {    
        ls6.add(rs.getString(1));
        ls6.add(rs.getString(2));
        ls6.add(rs.getString(3));
        //i++;
      } 
      //ls.toArray(ss);  
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.print(e);
    }
//ls.toArray(ss);
return ls6;
}
```

Comment: Why you want edittext to be dynamic , why you are not inflating them ?

Comment: it has to be dynamic coz the number of edittixt is depending on the number of fields that back from the webservice